# JQuery duplicate script/source code to support functionality

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am enjoying learning to code but have a frustrating issue I know little about.

I used the following code to support the site including a scrolling nav bar:

```
         <!-- jQuery -->
        <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>

        <!-- Bootstrap Core JavaScript -->
        <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

        <!-- Scrolling Nav JavaScript -->
        <script src="js/jquery.easing.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/scrolling-nav.js"></script>
```

.........

```
                    <div class="container navbar-container">

                        <h2>Scroll to a specific <br>restaurant:</h2>
                      <nav class="navbar navbar-default">


                        <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
                            <li><a href="#2west">2 WEST</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#13north">13 NORTH</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#15church">15 CHURCH</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#baileys"><h5>BAILEY'S CAFE-&dollar;Deal!</h5></a></li>
                            <li><a href="#barrelhouse">THE BARRELHOUSE</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#beekman"><h5>BEEKMAN BAR &AMP; EATERY-&dollar;Deal!</h5></a></li>
```

.....

```
                    </ul>

                  </nav>

                </div>      

            </body>

           </div>
```

Then, to add popup box I added:

        
        
        
...

#### Hours

```
                                    <div data-role="popup" id="westhours">
                                    <h2>Monday-Thursday 11:00am - 11:00pm<br>
                                    Friday &amp; Saturday 11:00am - 12:00am<br>
                                    Sunday 10:30am - 10:00pm<br>

                                    Please note: Kitchen closes 1 hour prior to closing.</h2>
                                    </div>
                                    </li>
                                   </ul>
```

With both code segments, the scrolling nav bar doesn't link to sections. 
If I delete the nav bar code, the popup box works.
If I delete the original section, the popbox doesn't work.

I know I must have conflicting source and script code, but I can't find the right ones to delete so both the popup box and navbar function!

Please help!

Comment: Check your browser console

Comment: Why is `<body>` tag being closed before `<div>` tag? You should close <body> tag at end of all content.

Comment: </body>
    <footer class="footer">
        
        <div class="container">
            
            <div class="row">
                
                <div class="col-md-12">
                
                    <div id="copyright">
                        
                        <p>Contact &#58; admin@camenterprises.com </p>
                        <p>Copyright &copy; 2017 CAM Enterprises</p>
                    
                    </div>
        
                </div>
       
            </div>
     
        </div>
   
    </footer>


</html>

Comment: I've only been coding for two months...trying my best!

Comment: The script and source I added for the popup box is: <!---Popup Box---------------->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css">
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>

Answer (score 0):

take [this](https://github.com/BlackrockDigital/startbootstrap-scrolling-nav/blob/master/index.html) working code from author of pluggin. Then add new tabs, rename them.